# PHP how to check if fsockopen still good?

Tags: php, fsockopen

When my script opens a connection in PHP with `fsockopen` and enters into endless `while` loop, how can I check *inside the loop* if connection is still good?

e.g. if my internet went out, the loop would still go, and that is bad.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fgets() fwrite() and so on will probably fail. Did you try [feof](http://php.net/feof)()?